# Regular expression in XSD schema: mix and max size of two combined elements

Tags: regex, xsd

I would like to create a restriction for an XSD type to only allow an element of size 0 to 64, a dot, and another element of size 0 to 64. I tried this, but without success.

```
<xs:simpleType name="myString_Type">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="^([a-zA-Z\-]){0-64}.$([a-zA-Z\-]){0-64}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think you mean: [`^[a-zA-Z-]{0,64}[.][a-zA-Z-]{0,64}$`](http://regex101.com/r/yQ3jE7)

Comment: Yes, you´re right and very quick! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`^` and `$` aren't used for regex in XSD - it always matches from the start and end, as if they were there. Therefore, just omit them:

```
[a-zA-Z\-]{0,64}\.[a-zA-Z\-]{0,64}
```

And escape the `.` (or use a character class as NullUserException said).

From the [XML Schema part 2: datatypes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#regexs) spec:

> Unlike some popular regular expression languages (including those defined by Perl and standard Unix utilities), the regular expression language defined here implicitly anchors all regular expressions at the head and tail, as the most common use of regular expressions in ·pattern· is to match entire literals.

Their example is to use `A.*Z` not `^A.*Z$`

Because `^` and `$` aren't special characters, it will just try to match them in your xml document.

*It's been said that unix is a collection of incompatible regular expression syntaxes, so by not following the unix standard, they are following the unix tradition.*

---

You can test this example at: http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/ (test instance from NullUserException)

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="eg" type="myString_Type"/>

  <xs:simpleType name="myString_Type">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z\-]{0,64}\.[a-zA-Z\-]{0,64}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>

<eg>something.something-else</eg>
```

Comment: Yes, you also had it in your answer.  Your way looks cleaner, but I think it's clearer for exceptional semantics to have exceptional syntax.  Your way is an exception to an exception -  cleverer, more complex, and more for the reader to know.  Reasonable persons could disagree on which is more important! BTW: I really liked your use of an online regex tester ([here](http://regex101.com/r/yQ3jE7), there's probably one for xsd testing... um best I've found is http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/#.UKJI_2ZCOBs, but no where near as nice as your regex tool. I'll add my example.

Comment: @NullUserException BTW I think a real problem with regex is testing them.  How can you be sure of what they will accept, and what they won't?  This is intrinsically hard, because regex are already an optimally compact way to express the language they accept/match, so I think you just have to understand them. But regex are always tricky, even for experts, hence jwz's "2 problems" quip. Your regex tool helps in understanding, and testing specific instances... but I wonder if there exists a way to provide more assistance in checking their language (what they match), in general...